# Why does multiple "collection" URL parameters in REST search request return no results?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

According to the MarkLogic docs, the "collection" parameter can appear multiple times in a GET request to the REST Client API; however, the following returns 0 results:

```
/LATEST/search?q=&collection=GEWN&collection=TSJN
```

whereas an XQuery specifying both collections on the same database does return the expected results:

```
count(collection(("GEWN","TSJN")))
```

=>
90871

Using REST API to query one named collection individually returns expected results also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collections provided by URI parameter are AND related. The equivalent provided as a query would be:

```
<search:query>
<search:and-query>
    <search:collection-query>
        <search:uri>GEWN</search:uri>
    </search:collection-query>
    <search:collection-query>
        <search:uri>TSJN</search:uri>
    </search:collection-query>
</search:and-query>
</search:query>
```

When multiple collections are passed to a single `fn:collection()` or `cts:collection-query()` call, the collections are OR related.  To get the equivalent, provide the following query:

```
<search:query>
<search:collection-query>
    <search:uri>GEWN</search:uri>
    <search:uri>TSJN</search:uri>
</search:collection-query>
</search:query>
```

Here's the reference for the collection query in JSON:

```
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_76890
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be the case for /v1/qbe interface, but I would like to achieve this with /v1/search and the collection* parameter: http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search

Comment: The structured query above works with the /v1/search endpoint. (It is not a QBE.) You can POST the structured query as a payload (with or without query text to parse) or pass the structured query with GET as the structuredQuery URL parameter.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I have a feeling I'll be using structured queries often moving ahead.